# Android Swipelistview no longer working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

**Hi everyone,**

I'm trying to implement a swipelistview into an android project with Android Studio, of course i'm using gradle, so i try to download the library from a repository, some odd things I realised so far:

The git repository of [47deg/swipelistview](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) is no longer working. (404)

Also the repository from where gradle tries to download the library is no longer accessible 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public'

The project worked like a charm just one week ago, I have an APK witch is deployed in my phone and i'm looking to it as am writing this question.

This happened days ago when I tried to open the project to do some enhancement to the app, nothing related to the swipelistview thought. And when I try to build Android studio says Cannot resolve

> com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar

I tried removing snapshot@aar, changing version of swipelistview... no result.

**Question:**

Is there a problem with the repository I'm trying to download from?

If not, what are other libraries that can replace the swipelistview library?

I also checked all the related stackoverflow questions, I updated my Android Studio, changed version of gradle, tried to find a Jar of the library, but all of this without any positive result.

Thanks in advance for any efforts you put in this thread. I'm available for any clarifications.

Comment: It seems like the project was deleted. As an alternative, take a look at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.2t4mn5gcp).

Comment: have you finally found working repo?

Comment: Nope, we downloaded a Jar and added it to the project manually, you can google nineoldroids